# MySql Sub Select

Tags: mysql

I need to query a table and gather counts with and without a column value.

What is the count of records that contain column value on 'src' and the count without.

**Problem**

Results contain one day only instead of every day on each row. Each row has same values.

**Results Expected**

DAY, CONTAINS VALUE, DOESN'T CONTAIN VALUE

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(edate,'%Y-%m-%d') as day,

(SELECT 
COUNT(id) FROM  entries WHERE src='a string' and color = 'red') with_value,

(SELECT 
COUNT(id) FROM  entries WHERE src='' and color = 'red') without_value

FROM entries 

GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC
```

Comment: check this if it can help you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11aa6/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without subqueryes using this technique:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(edate,'%Y-%m-%d') as day,
    SUM(src = 'a string') as with_value,
    SUM(src = '') as without_value

FROM entries 

GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC
```

What I did there was take advantage of the fact that MySQL [does not have a Boolean data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html), but rather `TRUE` is identical to `1`, and `FALSE` to `0`, in effect having the `SUM` act as a `COUNT` of rows that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(edate, '%Y-%m-%d') as day,
       SUM(src = 'a string' and color = 'red') as with_value,
       SUM(src = '' and color = 'red') as without_value
FROM entries 
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC;
```

In MySQL boolean expressions are treated as 0 (for false) and (1 for true) in an integer context.  This makes them convenient for aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want per-day aggregate results then you need to perform the grouping by day in the query(-ies) where you compute the aggregate(s).  You are grouping in a parent query instead.

In any event, you don't need subqueries for this, and it would be better to avoid them:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(edate,'%Y-%m-%d') as day,
    SUM(CASE WHEN src='a string' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE)
      AS with_value
    SUM(CASE WHEN src='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE)
      AS without_value
FROM entries
WHERE color = 'red'
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC
```

Comment: For you version to actually work you need to have `ELSE NULL`. See the manual for the "why?": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: I've edited my answer to also explain why there is absolutely no need to explicitly cast to numbers.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru Though there is no *need* to convert to numbers, doing so makes the meaning of the query clearer.  YMMV.